# How to start the code from where it has stopped in a list of million files?

Tags: python, list

I have a folder of 1 million photos. Suddenly my code stopped running at 88,001th file. The problem is with the file itself. My question here is: How to start my code from 88,002 th file.

```py
text1=[]
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
file_names=[]
for file in os.listdir('C:/BackUp/PhD/Data_from_Core_AP/Python/GeoTaggingWellsImages/filtered_images/Chittoor'):
    if file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        file_names.append(file)
        print(file)
        path = 'C:/BackUp/PhD/Data_from_Core_AP/Python/GeoTaggingWellsImages/filtered_images/Chittoor/'+file
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        crop_img = img[365:385,10:395]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(crop_img,245 ,255, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/BackUp/PhD/Data_from_Core_AP/Python/GeoTaggingWellsImages/filtered_images/temp.jpeg", gray)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("C:/BackUp/PhD/Data_from_Core_AP/Python/GeoTaggingWellsImages/filtered_images/temp.jpeg"), config='outputbase digits')
        temp=[]
        file = file.strip(".jpeg")
        temp.append(file)
        temp.append(text)
        text1.append(temp)
        f1=open("temp.txt",'a')
        f1.write(str(temp).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")+'\n')
        f1.close()
```

Comment: For next time, `try except` will prevent the code from stop working.

Comment: `str(temp).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'",""` => `",".join(temp)` try this :)

Comment: Use [`try..except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: also check returned image from `img = cv2.imread(path)` as if fails it returns `None`... in that case skip. And last, store the name of the latest processed file / index in a file to be able to skip to this image next time if the script stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `os.listdir(path)` returns a list, you can skip the first 88001 elements like so:

```
os.listdir(path)[88001:]
```

However, note that this really skips 88001 *files*, not 88801 *jpeg's*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) something along these lines:

```
from itertools import islice

    ...
start = 88002
files = os.listdir('C:/BackUp/PhD/Data_from_Core_AP/Python/GeoTaggingWellsImages/filtered_images/Chittoor')

for file in isclice(files, start-1, None):            
    if file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        ...
```